# Solarium query where query does not exactly match field

Tags: solr, solarium

I am new to Solr 6.0 & Solarium integration. I have the set up running but results are not being returned where fields do
not exactly match query. e.g I have a url field containig `'http://ayodeji.com'` or `'http://ayo-tuntun.com'` but a query for 'ayo' does not return these rows, Although they are returned with `*:*` queries in the Solr admin section. I have changed string to text in the managed-schema file but still wont work.
Please help
Below is the code from Solarium dismax example that I am using. Thank you.

```
    $client = new Solarium\Client($config);

$query = $client->createSelect();

$dismax = $query->getDisMax();

$dismax->setQueryFields('url^5 author^3 body^1 title');

$searchTerm = 'ayo';

$query->setQuery($searchTerm);

$resultset = $client->select($query);

echo 'NumFound: '.$resultset->getNumFound();

foreach ($resultset as $document) {

    echo '<hr/><table>';

    // the documents are also iterable, to get all fields
    foreach ($document as $field => $value) {
        // this converts multivalue fields to a comma-separated string
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = implode(', ', $value);
        }
        echo '<tr><th>' . $field . '</th><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use WordDelimiterFilter to split url by small parts.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

```
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" types="wdfftypes.txt"
            generateNumberParts="1" catenateNumbers="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
            catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" 
            stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="0" />
    </analyzer>
```

I have attached an image of tested results.

[image]

On the left side of an analysis tool you can see that ayo keyword has been matched.

My example of text_general fieldType

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false"  positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> 
     <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" types="wdfftypes.txt"
            generateNumberParts="1" catenateNumbers="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
            catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" 
            stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="0" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" types="wdfftypes.txt"
            generateNumberParts="1" catenateNumbers="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
            catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"
            stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="0" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Comment: Pardon my late reply, I was making the adjustments but was getting errors, turns out its the `wdfftypes.txt` , so I created the file and placed in the same location as managed-schema and the queries work partially. Instances like the two examples are working where the word starts with `ayo` or has an hypen in between works very flawlessly. But where the word is at the end of the whole word e.g `freeayo` or `needayo` does not return. I will read the doc link your provided. Accept my appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not search for substrings. I.e.: it is the normal behaviour that a search for “ello” does not find a document containing “helloworld”. If you want that you should use `*ello*` as search string.